# Markdown inside DataTable is adding paragraph around it

Tags: python, markdown, plotly-dash

When markdown is used in DashTable, an additional `<p>` tag is added making the cell and intern all rows larger.

```py
import dash
from dash import dash_table
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    [
        {'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 2, 'Col3': 'Text3'},
        {'Col1': 4, 'Col2': 5, 'Col3': 'Text6'}
    ],
    [
        {'name': 'Col1', 'id': 'Col1'},
        {'name': 'Col2', 'id': 'Col2'},
        {'name': 'Col3', 'id': 'Col3', 'presentation':'markdown'},
    ]
)

app.run_server(host='localhost', port=5050)
```

[image]

Is there a way to control this from `markdown_options`?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856211/how-to-align-a-markdown-cell-with-a-link-in-dash-datatable#comment132148341_73856211) in the body of the question. Add

`css=[dict(selector= "p", rule= "margin: 0; text-align: center")]`

to the datatable.